# My MultiBit is unable to connect

Tags: multibit, mac, connection

I have installed my MultiBit wallet and there is red "connecting" sign in left bottom corner. Wallet never connects. When I try it from another place (my friends house) everything is ok.

It is obvious that its network problem in my place. I have public IP and port 8333 is properly forwarded. I am using Mac OS X 10.8.5.

I have no idea what else to try or where to look for some error messages. Do you have any ideas what else to try or where to look for some clues?

Comment: You shouldn't need to forward port 8333 for MultiBit since it doesn't accept incoming connections.  Do you have a firewall?  Is it blocking outgoing connections?

Answer (score 1):

For anybody with common problem. It was DNS related problem.

Message from console:
01.01.14 21:06:52,881 mDNSResponder[38]: mDNSSendDNSMessage: write msg length failed -1/2
01.01.14 21:06:52,882 mDNSResponder[38]: ERROR: mDNSPlatformWriteTCP - send Broken pipe

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling antivirus to see if it connects or enabling multibit connection in the antivirus> firewall itself if this option is available. Or, check your router firewall for no restrictions  and that upnp Universal Plug and Play connection is allowed.